# How to recover from Boost ASIO async_handshake error

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, asio

I have followed the examples for creating an ASIO SSL client and my application works fine as long as there are no network errors encountered.  I used Clumsy to simulate dropped packets between my client app and the server and that is when I have errors I cannot recover from.  Specifically, the call to async_connect will invoke my connection handler which calls async_handshake.  The call to async_handshake never returns.  If I introduce an async timer to interrupt async_handshake, I get control back in my application, I then delete the socket and create a new one and attempt to connect again by calling io_context->post with the address of my function that will call async_connect.  The io_context->post call will throw an exception every time.  The exception states I am trying to access an iterator that is out of bounds, but I do not have any iterators in my connect call.  My question is, how do I recover from dropped packets in the async_handshake function?  Not interrupting async_handshake with a timer leaves my application in a hung state waiting for the SSL handshake to complete.  Using a timer seems to cause the Boost io_context run function to throw an exception.  How should I attempt to resolve this?